# Running AWS Batch Job on the JAR artifact from S3 bucket

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, executable-jar, aws-batch

In one of specific requirement, we need to use a Jar executable provided by other team in one of S3 bucket in a aws batch. The plan is to configure a aws batch which will spawn a EC2 instance, will copy the jar file from the s3 bucket and will run the java -jar command on the same jar with intended command line parameters.

Problem is,

1. the amazon:linux image does not have aws client installed so we are not able to use the aws s3 cp command in the job definition to copy the executable to the EC2 instance. getting following error,

```
CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "aws": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

2. with the wget command, the executable gets downloaded to EC2 from the s3 bucket; but the bash command in the job definition, is not able to distinguish the next command. Say wget  && java -jar executable.jar -> here it tries to process wget on '&&', tried multiple ways to provide two commands in single bash line but did not work. Getting following errors,
   `wget: unable to resolve host address java` <- without using ampersand in bash of job definition
   `wget: unable to resolve host address ‘&&’` <- with ampersand etc. separators for commands in bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your scenario right, I believe you're passing the command `wget <url> -O executable.jar && java -jar executable.jar` as the executable command. The container doesn't run this in a shell; it just views it as a single command with a strange set of arguments. Instead you could run it in a shell with `bash -c "wget <url> -O executable.jar && java -jar executable.jar"`. You might need to use `sh` if `bash` isn't available in your container.

Regarding the AWS CLI, you should be able to install it in Amazon Linux with `yum install awscli`. I believe it would pick up the credentials from your container, which you can configure in Batch to have access to your S3 bucket.